# Problemas con Worpress plugin Advance Custon Filed

Tags: wordpress, plugin

Buenos dias usuarios presento un problema con un plugin en WP segun tengo entendido este plugin [Advanced Custom Fields for WordPress Developers.](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)
Personaliza campo en el admin de tu pagina como en este [ejemplo](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/select/#settings) 
Cree un campo segun los pasos a mostrar y en el template lo muestras de estas maneras:

Basico: `<p>Color: <?php the_field('color'); ?></p>`

Multiple:

```
<?php

// vars 
$colors = get_field('color');


// check
if( $colors ): ?>
<p>Color: <?php echo implode(', ', $colors); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

O segun este otro ejemplo

```
<?php

// vars
$field = get_field_object('color');
$value = $field['value'];
$label = $field['choices'][ $value ];

?>
<p>Color: <span class="color-<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $label; ?></span></p>
```

Resulta que en ninguno de los caso me muestra el contenido no da error ni tampoco me arroja el campo

Comment: ¿Pero dónde dices que no te lo muestra, en la pantalla de edición o en el contenido de tu plantilla?

Comment: La del contenido de mi plantilla osea usao un template llamado freelanceengenie el template posee una plantilla de registro de usuario llamada page-register alli quiero mostrar los campos personalizado de un registro de usuario

Comment: @A.Cedano puedes ayudarme con esto?

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir los pantallazos de la configuración de los `fields` en `AFC`? Así como el valor que tienen en la parte de administración.